# Read all rows of a table

Tags: php

I created a table in Wampserver64 with 7 columns (`companyname`, `cod`, `bign`, `stop`, `date`, `time`, `price`) and 5 rows. In the PHP section I want to get the information of all rows as JSON output, but in the output only the last row information is read. I provided the PHP code and output below.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','u656325986_login');



$response=array();



$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from travel");


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    enter code here
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp=array();
        $temp["companyname"]=$row["companyname"];
        $temp["cod"]=$row["cod"];
        $temp["bign"]=$row["bign"];
        $temp["stop"]=$row["stop"];
        $temp["data"]=$row["data"];
        $temp["time"]=$row["time"];
        $temp["price"]=$row["price"];


        $response["travel"]=array();
        array_push($response["travel"],$temp);



    }

    $response["t"]=1;
    echo json_encode($response);



}
else{


    $response["message"]="not fonud";
    echo json_encode($response);

}


?>
```

#### Output

[image]

> ```
> {"travel":[{"companyname":"alborz ","cod":"333333333","bign":"yazd","stop":"gheshm","data":"22/22/33","time":"23:60","price":"123456789"}],”t”:1}
> ```

As you can see, the output is just the end of the line. The rest of the rows are not read.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new empty array on each iteration.

Define this outside of the while loop so each array_push will add items to it:

```
$response["travel"]=array();
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should put `$response["travel"]=array();` outside while loop
 , replace your code to be

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','u656325986_login');



$response=array();



$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from travel");


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $response["travel"]=array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp=array();
        $temp["companyname"]=$row["companyname"];
        $temp["cod"]=$row["cod"];
        $temp["bign"]=$row["bign"];
        $temp["stop"]=$row["stop"];
        $temp["data"]=$row["data"];
        $temp["time"]=$row["time"];
        $temp["price"]=$row["price"];

        array_push($response["travel"],$temp);



    }

    $response["t"]=1;
    echo json_encode($response);



}
else{


    $response["message"]="not fonud";
    echo json_encode($response);

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need most of the code anyway.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','u656325986_login');

$response=array('travel' => array());

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from travel");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $response["travel"][] = $row;
    }

    $response["t"]=1;
    echo json_encode($response);

}
else{


    $response["message"]="not fonud";
    echo json_encode($response);

}


?>
```